# VSCode上でモジュールの解決ができない

Tags: python

下記のコードをVScodeで入力したら、

```
インポート "requests" をソースから解決できませんでした
```

というエラーが発生しました。requestsモジュールについてはインストール済みです。

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.command()
async def pokemon(ctx, *, name):
    # PokeAPIを使用してポケモンの情報を取得する
    url = f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{name}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        # 必要な情報を取得する
        id = data['id']
        name = data['name']
        height = data['height']
        weight = data['weight']
        types = [t['type']['name'] for t in data['types']]
        abilities = [a['ability']['name'] for a in data['abilities']]
        # レスポンスを送信する
        await ctx.send(f"ID: {id}\n名前: {name}\n高さ: {height}\n重さ: {weight}\nタイプ: {types}\n特性: {abilities}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{name}の情報を取得できませんでした。")

client.run('トークン')
```

Comment: 「というエラーが発生しました。」とのことですが、VSCode(lint)が出している警告ではなくPythonインタープリターが出しているエラーで間違いないでしょうか？

Comment: 複数のpython環境が存在していて、相応しいものを設定していないとかありませんか？ これらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Import "requests" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource](https://qiita.com/te-k/items/cb7dff6a344387907307), [import requests がうまくいきません](https://teratail.com/questions/372498), [VSCodeでrequestsをimportしてエラーでたときの対処法](https://note.com/onepera/n/n02483e86ccc6), [Import "requests" could not be resolved from source](https://teratail.com/questions/339279), [Python requestsライブラリについて質問です](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14280191954)